# Element is not clickable at

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, saucelabs

I am facing **Element is not clickable** error while running my selenium scripts in sauce labs when I am using Chrome version 61. But, If I downgrade the chrome version from 61 to 59 then that error is gone.

Any inputs to fix error with version 61 will be appreciated.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Try using javascript, and scrollintoview the element needing to be clicked on.  If that still doesn't work, try using zoom.

Comment: I don't think the issue from Chrome 61,  like click feature should already stable since more earlier version.  add some sleep before click to debug on Chrome 61, If sleep work, change sleep to explicity wait.

Comment: From other side, if you met this issue when click anything, we can say Chrome 61 has issue on click.

Comment: Which version of the chromedriver are you using? If its not the latest one I suggest you update it. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154711/chrome-browser-61v-problems-with-click-on-element-outside-visible-area/46167505#46167505)

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem I have after my Chrome just recently updated to v61!
I see a lot of "Element is not clickable" errors on the test reports, although nothing has been changed. This is due to an issue of a chromedriver. Please, find more information here:
[Chome 61, ChromeDriver 2.32 Click on element for mobile device emulators throws WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339180/chome-61-chromedriver-2-32-click-on-element-for-mobile-device-emulators-throws)