# Chome 61, ChromeDriver 2.32 Click on element for mobile device emulators throws WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have tests that were perfectly working in Chrome 60 and ChromeDriver 2.31, but after Chrome updated to 61 version I had to update ChromeDriver to 2.32. And now I am getting sporadic org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (X, Y) - in all tests that are run for mobile device emulators such as "iPhone 6 Plus" browser mode,

for example.

As a workaround I would probably use scroll to element before the click, but it's just a quick fix and it's better to know where this issue comes from. Is it the issue of the current latest Chrome and driver releases? Is it going to be fixed soon?

Issue is reproduced on both local and remote webdriver.

Stacktrace:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not
>   clickable at point (182, 3724)   (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.91)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550
>   (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 115 milliseconds Build info:
>   version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info:
>   host: 'xxx', ip: '10.100.8.33', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch:
>   'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
>   mobileEmulationEnabled=true, networkConnectionEnabled=false,
>   chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.32.498550
>   (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),
>   userDataDir=C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir5912_31757},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=true,
>   version=61.0.3163.91, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false,
>   nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}] Session ID:
>   2ead932fef8d0d923286ac41c8fffe50 Command duration or timeout: 257
>   milliseconds

I guess it relates to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1852

Answer (score 4):

Chrome driver Developers are aware that the fix is not working properly in mobile device emulate mode. A fix for that is coming in ChromeDriver 2.33.

Answer (score 1):

you need to downgrade your chrome version to 59.0 (32 bit), as there is some with issue with the new chrome update.
or 
you need to scroll to element first and then try to click

Comment: How can I downgrade chrome if it does not have a standalone versions installers?

Comment: is that device is having pre-installed chrome?

Comment: the emulator i use is having option to install/uninstall

Comment: it's not a devices - it's chrome on windows, but it launches in responsive design mode iPhone 6 user agent

Answer (score 1):

I am not absolutely sure but your issue sounds very much like mine one. My tests appeared to be not able to scroll to the element using the built-in move_to_element() Selenium method after my browser was updated.

Here is my workaround written in python

```
   def scroll_to_element(element):
       self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, %d);" % 
       element.location['y'])
```

As a temporary solution – try to scroll to the element an then try to click it. Hope this helps you for now.

Comment: Yes, the workaround with scroll before the click makes the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are alternate solution for this:

First maximize the window:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Second, You can use the Action class to `moveToElement`method and access it

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By("element"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

Comment: Yes, I can use it, but don't want to :) I am curious if it's an issue in the last 2.32 chromedriver itself.

Comment: May be it is an issue. But I am not confident say yes. I don't have proof of yet. As we know selenium don't have vendor support. so we can rely on Alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

try to click using javascript its works for me.

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfd"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: The same - Yes, I can use it, but don't want to :) I am curious if it's an issue in the last 2.32 chromedriver itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (movetoelement does nothing in mode movilemulation with chromedriver2.32 and Chrome61+) and the only solution for me was back to Chrome60. You can obtains older versions of chrome in
https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

When chromedriver2.33 arrives then i will test again against Chrome61+